# Taylor series in C - math.h vs own implementation

Tags: c, taylor-series

Although I find some posts with Taylor series here, I'd like to ask for support:
I wrote C code for `sin(x)` calculation, based on Taylor equation.
As arguments my functions takes rad value and expected length of Taylor series.

What I'm observing is that my function returns same value as sine from `math.h` only till `x <= 1.8` -> all returned values above this value differs. Here is the code:

Here is code in online debugger (it's first time I'm pasting, so it might be not working)
https://onlinegdb.com/f4ymuMloW

whole code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int factorial(int x) {
    if (x == 0 || x == 1) 
        return 1;

    return x * factorial(x-1);
}

/*
    sin(x) = sum[k=0, n] ((-1^k) * x^(2k+1))/(2k+1)!        
 */

double taylorSine(double x, int k) {
    double ret = 0.0f;
    for (int i = 0 ; i < k; i++) {
        double l = pow(-1, i) * pow(x, 2 * i + 1);
        long long unsigned int m = factorial(2 * i + 1);
        ret += l/(double)m;
    }
    return ret;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    float low,up;
    /* default */
    int sumsteps = 5;
    double res = 0.01f;

    if (argc == 1) {
        low = -3.14f;
        up = 3.14f;            
    } 
    else if (argc == 3) {
        low = atof(argv[1]);
        sumsteps = atoi(argv[2]);
    } 
    else {
        printf("wrong number of args\n");
        return 0;
    }

    double r = taylorSine(low, sumsteps);
    printf("%f,%f\n", low, r);
    printf("sin(x)=%f\n", sin(low));        

    return 0;
}
```

and outputs:

```
Starting program: /home/a.out 0 7
0.000000,0.000000
sin(x)=0.000000
[Inferior 1 (process 2146) exited normally]
(gdb) run 1.57 7
Starting program: /home/a.out 1.57 7
1.570000,1.000000
sin(x)=1.000000
[Inferior 1 (process 2147) exited normally]
(gdb) run 3.14 7
Starting program: /home/a.out 3.14 7
3.140000,0.002643
sin(x)=0.001593
[Inferior 1 (process 2148) exited normally]
(gdb) run 6.28 7
Starting program: /home/a.out 6.28 7
6.280000,9.053029
sin(x)=-0.003185
[Inferior 1 (process 2149) exited normally]
(gdb)
```

Comment: Start by changing `factorial` to use `unsigned long long` instead of `int`.

Comment: Try larger sumsteps. Accuracy of taylor series quickly worsens with magnitude of x

Comment: Good implementations of `sin` do not merely evaluate a Taylor series. They reduce the argument modulo 2π (often into two parts, effectively a sector number and a residue modulo some fraction of π), then apply an engineered polynomial, possibly a minimax polynomial (selected to minimize relative error rather than absolute error). And some extended precision may be used during these steps.

Comment: Why are you using `pow` and `factorial` when you know these numbers from the previous iteration and some simple maths (less computer intensive) can compute the next value from the previous one!

Comment: @EdHeal thanks for suggestions, however i was never good at such optimalizations, so i stick with repeting same operations, althoguh i know that x^7 = x^5 (prev) * x^2 and so on :) . Regarding factorial - what im thinking is just to create lookup table, but if you have something faster/better/optimal - could you give me some hints?

Answer (score 2):

Your factorial function will overflow (2*7+1)! == 1,307,674,368,000, try a double version instead.

```
double factorial(double x)
{
  double sum = 1.0;
  for (double y = 2.0; y < x; y += 1.0 )
  {
    sum*=y;
  }
  return sum;
}
```